# Math problem unsolved with Python - Cannot find the right answer

Tags: python, math, symbolic-math

I wrote this code with the purpose of solving this equation
[image: K Attenuator T formula]
where I have the values of R3 (630) and Z (600). But I didn't managed it to solve the equation. I received lots of errors and some wrong answers while working on the code. The answer for k should be 2.33333...

```
import math
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

# ATENUADOR PI
R3 = 630
Z = 600
k = symbols('k')
AdB = symbols('AdB')
k = solve((R3 * (k ** 2 - 1) / 2 * Z))
k = max(k)
```

The errors received by each k = solve(...) i used
`k = solve((R3 * (k ** 2 - 1) / 2 * Z))`

> k = 1

`k = solve(R2 * (k ** 2 - 1) / (2 * Z))`

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

`k = solve(R2=2 * Z * (k / k ** 2 - 1))`

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

`k = solve((R2 * k ** 2) - R2 - (2 * k * 2))`

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

There was still a formula that gave me the value of 1 + sqrt(2), close to the answer, but still not it

Consider R2 == R3

Comment: "I received lots of errors and some wrong answers while working on the code" - can you include the errors and the wrong answers in an edit to the question?

Comment: Your `solve` call doesn’t have an equals in it. In any case, please copy-paste the error message or show the wrong answer that this code gives. See [mre].

Comment: Possibly the part `/ 2 * Z` should read `/ (2 * Z)`...?

Comment: This is a simple quadratic equation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve is solving for 0, so you can do

```py
from sympy import symbols
R3 = 630
Z = 600
k = symbols("k")
k_ans = solve(2*Z*(k/(k*k-1))-R3)
print(k_ans)
```

Which gives `[-3/7, 7/3]` as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrongly defined the argument of `solve()` function

The correct one is:

```
res = solve((R3 * (k ** 2 - 1) - (2 * Z * k)))
```

You can easily check it by solving this equation on paper

Answer (score 0):

```
630.Z² - 2.600.Z - 630 = 0  <-> Z = -3/7 or Z = 7/3.
```